# Neo4j - edges between same nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nodes, graph-visualization

I'm running the example on https://neo4j.com/graphgist/eurovision-votes

I did everything like them but the problem is, I don't get the same graph as them. For example, for the query 12, I get that
[image]

So, my main problem is that I would like to have only maximum one edge between 2 nodes like in their example.

Any idea of how to do that?

Comment: Hi @k-hua, let me know if my answer has helped you to solve your issue. Also, if the answer was helpful, can you [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) as the right answer? This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi, thanks but no. I tried with both checked and unchecked "Connect result nodes" and it doesn't merge the edges. When the option is checked, the results is even weirder as any queries return me all the nodes and the edges

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is probably related to an Neo4j Browser configuration called "Connect result nodes". When this option is checked, Neo4j browser will connect the resultant nodes in the graph visualization mode when a connection between these nodes exist.

To disable this behavior you should go to the section **"Graph Visualization"** of Neo4j Browser Settings and uncheck the option **"Connect result nodes"** as show in the image below:

[image: Disabling connect result nodes]